# Entity framerwork - get tree struct from table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, treeview

I have 2 tables.
1 with column FromId and ToId, 2 with column Id, Path and I need to get all connection like tree struct:

| FromId | ToId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 10 |
| 2 | 4 |

[image]

I want to present this data in angular material tree so I need something like this:

```
  const TREE_DATA = {
  Element: {
    'id: 13 path:': null,
    'Id: 1 Path: ___' : {
      'id:2 path:___': ['id:3 path:___', 'id:4 path:___'],
    }
  }
};
```

[image]

Can it be achieved with one query?

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a single query. At least when I tried doing something similar, I ended up having to load all required data into memory and building the tree from there.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought my knowledge was too little to do something like that

Comment: Pretty sure you'd have to use raw sql, view or procedure.... https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/recursive-data-with-entity-framework-core-and-sql-server

Comment: @Dnomyar96 can you post your solution? I have problem to get corectly this data even in few query

Comment: Though if you simply load everything in a query, the navigation properties should all be linked in memory. Even with NoTracking after ef core 5 (from memory). That doesn't help you to write the query for a subset of the table.